# How can I remove packages using preseed?

Tags: installation, preseed

I'm setting up an automated "no questions asked" preseed system and using Dustin Kirkland's [server preseed](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/03/ubuntu-server-quick-install-no.html) as an example.

He uses the following line to install three packages as part of the automated install:

`d-i pkgsel/include string byobu vim openssh-server`

I am looking  for the *inverse* of this, basically be able to remove packages as part of the automated install.

- I've checked the [Installation Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-contents.html)
- I've checked this [example preseed](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt), but it's not clear if this is the canonical list of every single option available.

I am thinking I need to to use `d-i preseed/late_command string apt-remove packagename` to clean up stuff I don't want when the install is done, but I am not sure

Comment: Definitely how I would go about it.  Not big on preseed though.  I use pseudopackages and start from a base install that doesn't have anything I don't want.

Comment: No one from the desktop team or server team looked at this question?

Comment: I've tried this approach to remove packages but it is not working for me :(. https://gist.github.com/lmayorga1980/6d698a5d5425c676ecdd

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't an option to purge o delete a package in the preseed configuration script but you can use this command....

**d-i preseed/late_command**

```
This command is run just before the install finishes, but when there is
still a usable /target directory. You can chroot to /target and use it
directly, or use the apt-install and in-target commands to easily install
packages and run commands in the target system.
"in-target" means: chroot /target
d-i preseed/late_command string [in-target] foo
```

example :

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
            in-target apt-get remove packagename
```

you can also run a script :

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
        in-target wget http://........./postinst.sh -O /root/postinst.sh; \
        in-target /bin/bash /root/postinst.sh
```

or install a group of DEB files :

```
d-i preseed/late_command               string \
    for deb in /hd-media/*.deb; do cp $deb /target/tmp; \
    chroot /target dpkg -i /tmp/$(basename $deb); done
```

Comment: Just a comment: I had to invoke `apt-get -y remove packagename`.

Answer (score 0):

The example pressed is just an example; it does not contain all possible d-i combinations, but just those more common.

Personally, I have never tried to remove packages from an install, so I am not sure there is a specific d-i command for it; it sounds like your `d-i preseed late_command` should work. A quick search on the d-i docs did not produce anything... But, of course, Colin would know ;-)

Alternatively, you could start from a basic server, and then add whatever you want:

```
tasksel tasksel/first   multiselect     Basic Ubuntu server
...
d-i preseed/late_command string apt-install whatever else
```