# Installing packages upon installation automatically

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, automation, preseed

I commonly install/remove a bunch of software after installing Ubuntu, I wonder about the methods to automate it.

Is anything like `/etc/apt/packages` where I could define which packages I want?

Pressed configuration files work on initial setup, however I'd like it to work regardless of the status of the system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove packages using preseed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54809/how-can-i-remove-packages-using-preseed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any file for that. Just create a file `packages` in your home folder. List there all the needed packages and install them by

```
cat packages | xargs sudo apt-get install
```

or

```
xargs -a packages sudo apt-get install
```

The same way you can remove or purge a list of packages.

The list may look like

```
vlc
ubuntu-restricted-extras
mc
```

Comment: `dpkg --list | sed -nre 's/^ii +([^ ]+)+ +.*/\1/p'  > packages` - suggested addition.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a kickstart script and pxe boot with puppet and it will be completely configured auto-magically on first boot. Completely hands off.

Comment: Only real answer,  lol poor sports shows your just sad